# How much time is required to walk from Frankfurt Terminal 1 Z gates to C gates?

Tags: airport-terminals, frankfurt

I'm travelling to India from USA via Frankfurt. I have a layover of 1 hour and 35 mins at frankfurt. It would be really nice if someone can tell me how much time it takes to walk from Terminal 1 Z gates to Terminal 1 C gates?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How was your experience in reaching from a Z-gate to a C-gate in Frankfurt Airport's Terminal 1?

Comment: As Hilmar mentioned below, Z is very long. It took 15-20 mins of brisk walking to reach terminal 1 C gate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C and Z are unfortunately on opposite sides of Terminal 1, so it is quite a bit of a hike. Exact walking time depends on gate location (Z is very long) and your walking speed. I'd say 15-20 minutes.

Your best shot is probably to take the airside section of the SkyLine https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/transfer.detail.suffix.html/article/travel/terminal-transfer/terminal-transfer-via-skyline.html
I'm not sure that there is an airside walking connection anyway.

Comment: Thanks Hilmar. Is 1 hour 35 mins layover enough at frankfurt airport?

Comment: @Shrirang: Depends on the details:  If it's a single ticket with interlined bags, than this should be fine unless there are some major delays. If it is two separate tickets, this would be extremely difficult to make

Comment: yeah I'm travelling on a single ticket with interlined bags. Do I have to go through security check at frankfurt while changing the concourse?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe the SkyLine has an airside connection between Z and C but it's an unusual connection and I've never done it myself